# How to change SPC bind in info-mode

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I have this on my init.el and I still did not manage to make SPC do what I want in info-mode:

```
(unbind-key "SPC" Info-mode-map)
(unbind-key "SPC" Info-edit-map)
(unbind-key "SPC" Info-edit-mode-map)
(unbind-key "SPC" Info-link-keymap)
(unbind-key "SPC" Info-mode-line-node-keymap)
(unbind-key "SPC" Info-speedbar-key-map)
(unbind-key "SPC" info-tool-bar-map)
(bind-key "w" 'Info-scroll-up Info-mode-map)
(bind-key "SPC" 'counsel-M-x Info-mode-map)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `bind-key` or `unbind-key`. And you don't need to do any of the stuff you tried doing (seemingly blindly). Just do this:

```
(define-key Info-mode-map (kbd "SPC") 'counsel-M-x)
```

Do that *after* loading Info (e.g., do it on `Info-mode-hook`).

If that doesn't work then you are doing something else in your init file that interferes. In that case, recursively bisect your init file to find the problem.

Comment: You can also wrap it in `(with-eval-after-load "info" ...)`

Comment: @jpkotta: That's one way of doing it *after* loading Info.